# How to relate the queue with tree in bfs

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to implement BFS for insertion in Binary tree(Complete Binary tree) in java,

The logic i have read is ,It uses a Queue for inserting in a Tree

The queue is to keep the order of the items and a tree to store the items in left and right nodes

**For Ex:**

Queue-1 2 3

**Tree:**

root->        1

```
2            3
```

**Problem with Implementation:**

The following are my doubts

**1**.How to maintain pointers,one for Queue and one for tree seperately or use the same one.

**2**.Once the left & right childrens are filled ,then whether we should dequeue the element from the queue.

For Example:Once Elements 2 and 3 are added to 1 ,then whether 1 should be dequeued .

**3**.If it is dequeued,then how to iterate elements in the tree while filling?

Whether we need to use the element in queue and find the element  in tree and then insert ???

I am not clear with how insertion can occur with the help of Queue in Binary Tree.

Comment: tanx @redFIVE i tried it,but they are using Queue from Java Collections,I wanted to implement from the scratch without using Java Collections .Can you just give tips for that !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems correct. Few points I would like to mention here.

1. Enqueue the node from queue only when both of its children node are inserted.
2. Insert node value rather than whole node in queue for simplicity.
3. Keep a `hashmap` with mapping between node value and actual node.

With the above approach, you need to keep just one pointer of queue.